# Inconsistency between console.log occurences and Dev Tools Profiler rerenders count

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, performance-testing

I have a simple question for React experts.

I'm currently working on a React project and I need to optimize the display time. For that, I'm trying to delete all the useless renders of the components.

I have started to use React Dev Tool "Profiler". When recording one of my components called , it indicates 2 renders. But if I put a console.log in this component just before the "return", it appears 15 times !

So I don't understand :

- on one side, I'm told the component is only rerendered twice
- on the other side, the console.log appears 15 times in the console

I tried to add one console.log inside the return part, but it appears 15 times too.
I can't figure out my misconception of the rendering concept on this point.

Can someone help me with that please ?

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Invoking the body of a function component (your console.log) is most likely not the same as an actual render that hits the DOM. There is some machinery in-between the two.

Comment: use the `useEffect` hook to execute your `console.log` it should run according to each render (with some caveats depending on react version and dev/prod/strict modes).

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Could you please tell me more about this "in-between machinery" ? From 2 renders to 15 console.log, I imagine this can substantially affect the performance of my app...